# downcasting AnyObject to Int in Swift (using Sprite Kit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

First I save an integer into an `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
var levelNumber: Int = 3
var levelUserData: NSMutableDictionary = ["level": "\(levelNumber)"]
levelButton.userData = levelUserData
```

Later, I retrieve the integer:

```
var levelFromUserData: AnyObject! = levelButton.userData!.objectForKey("level")
```

This gives me the value I want, but I'm unable to use it as an integer. If I try downcasting like so...

```
var levelIntFromUserData: Int = levelFromUserData as Int  // also tried as?, as!
```

..the app crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you converting it to a string in the first place? In any case the answer is probably going to be that you can't cast because the types aren't compatible; you can ask the string to parse itself to an integer. But someone with better Swift knowledge can answer properly.

Comment: Converting to a string was a legacy mistake. Your `integerValue` solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting the level number into a string. A string cannot be typecast to an int because they're logically different things. But it can parse itself. E.g.

```
var levelIntFromUserData = levelUserData["level"]!.integerValue
```

You should definitely consider just storing as a number object natively. You'd still need the `integerValue` call but storage and conversion would be more efficient. E.g.

```
var levelUserData: NSMutableDictionary = ["level": levelNumber]
```